# Lookup value from other sql table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following sql statement:

```
select A.transactionNumber,
A.DealNumber      
A.Group
from TableOne A

inner join TableTwo B     
on A.transactionNumber = B.tranNumber     
where B.ID = 111111
```

this yields something like this

```
transactionnumber  |   DealNumber  |  Group
123                |   1           |   100
456                |   2           |   101
```

However, there's another table, tableThree, that translates the 'Group' into a string. It looks like this:

```
Group | GroupLookup
100   | Lookup1
101   | Lookup2
102   | Lookup3
```

So in summary, I'd like my select to return this:

```
transactionnumber  |   DealNumber  |  Group
123                |   1           |   Lookup1
456                |   2           |   Lookup2
```

I'm entirely sure that this is simple, however I'm a complete newbie and the presence of the first join in the select is throwing me, I'd very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood should be something like:

```
select A.transactionNumber,
A.DealNumber,     
C.GroupLookup AS [Group]
from TableOne A    
inner join TableTwo B     
on A.transactionNumber = B.tranNumber     
inner join TableThree C
on C.Group = A.Group
where B.ID = 111111
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. You added the second inner join, but there is no Group field in tableTwo (B). Group is in tableThree and if I change the line c.Group = B.Group to C.Group = A.Group then I get many more rows returned than the query I had before I tried to get the group lookup out.

Comment: So you need to join `TableThree` `Group` on `TableOne` `Group`. As you select `A.Group` and It returns group number, in `TableThree` are column `Group` too - which contains the same group number so you need join them and other column in `TableThree` which contains name of group is `GroupLookup` so you need to use It select clause. Check answer now.

Comment: Many thanks - increase in row number was due to the contents of the table, nothing to do with the query. Thanks again - really helpful